How to Configure Yate for SIP to ISUP Over M3UA and Back to SIP?
I'm setting up a Yate (Yet Another Telephony Engine) configuration to route calls from a SIP phone (A) through Yate A, using ISUP over M3UA to Yate B, and then to another SIP phone (B). The setup is as follows:
[sip phone A] -- SIP --> [yate A] -- ISUP over M3UA --> [yate B] -- SIP --> [sip phone B]

I need to know the specific configuration parameters to modify in ysigchan.conf, sigtransport.conf, and regexroutes.conf to achieve this. Here are the configurations I have so far:
ysigchan.conf:
[m3ua-gateway]
type=ss7-m3ua-gateway
; sig The underlying transport of this gateway
sig=sctp-link
; router: string: Name of the SS7 Router to attach to
; A boolean false value disables attaching a router (unlikely)
router=false
network=isup-test

;SS7 ISUP trunk
[isup-test]
type=ss7-isup
netindicator=national
pointcodetype=ITU
pointcode=0-0-6
remotepointcode=5
defaultpointcode=6
router=false

sigtransport.conf:
[sctp-link]
type=sctp
stream=false
local=172.16.100.120:5050
remote=172.16.100.120:5050
endpoint=false

Could someone guide me on what specific changes I need to make in these configuration files, and if there are any other configurations required?
Additional Context:

Yate A should handle the conversion from SIP to ISUP over M3UA.
Yate B should handle the conversion from ISUP over M3UA back to SIP.
The local and remote IP addresses for SCTP in sigtransport.conf are placeholders and can be adjusted as needed.
Any other necessary configurations or routing adjustments in regexroutes.conf?

What I've Tried:
I've configured ysigchan.conf and sigtransport.conf as shown above, but I'm unsure about the exact parameters for regexroutes.conf and if there are additional changes required in other configuration files to complete this setup.
Expected Outcome:
A properly configured Yate system where calls are successfully routed from SIP phone A, through Yate A and Yate B, and finally to SIP phone B using ISUP over M3UA in between.
